# permission error!

Tags: permissions

when I use command sudo su and enter my password, I can not see what the /root directory is containing exactly

```
root@root:~# pwd
/root
root@root:~# ls
Desktop
```

Comment: Please add console message of the issue while You are accessing the directories, also use `journalctl` to post more information we can work with.

Comment: Why would anyone help you when you are so rude? I voted to put this on hold again, it is very unclear. What does "does not anything!" mean? be more specific, no one can answer something so ambiguous.

Comment: It "does not anything"? Yet it boots up, lets you select a directory and produces an error message. Which is probably correct as well: you should, as an ordinary user, *not*  be able to view some directories.

Comment: mark kirby. I meant no offence! when you vote a post to hold no one can see that post for suggesting the solutions! (as I know). so why would you do that instead of just leaving it or asking for more information you need to answer that???? just as you expecting me to provide more information, I need to know what kind of information you need to know!

Comment: `root@root:~# ls` shows that you are in your home-directory. use `sudo su`,then `cd /root` to enter it and then `ls -a` to list all files.

Comment: the `pwd` shows that I'm in `/root` 
but `ls -a` shows these files ls -a
`.   .bash_history  .cache   .dbus    .local    .synaptic
..  .bashrc        .config  Desktop  .profile`
I think there is something wrong with this! I used to be able to gain the / directories from the graphical interface before but I'm not able to access now!

Comment: No, you typed `pwd /root` into the command-line. That does actually nothing. Use `cd /root` and you should see the difference in the following command-prompt. Or just use `ls -a /root`. http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

Comment: My main issue was how rude you were about it. People can still see on hold questions fine, the point of putting it on hold is to show you where you can improve the question.

Comment: @MarkKirby there were no rudeness at all! as I said I meant no offence. so please stop using this term about me if this is possible to you! I just could not understand what would you want to know more rather I was explained! people just put a question on hold without asking for any specific detail! and just say give us more detail! what detail??? they do not say that. so I just went out of mind and said do not put me on hold if you can not answer so that other people may understand what I'm talking about. (I didn't know people can discuss about a hold question.

Comment: @mook765 I used the command that you offering but I just didn't typed in here to short the massage.I typed `cd /` then `cd root` then I used `clear` command to clear the terminal in order to keep just necessary information after getting into the `/root`. I wanted to show you that I've already get to `/root` so I typed `pwd` to show me where am I, it answered `/root` then I used `ls -a` and it showed me what I've sent before. so now considering that I used the command you said, (`cd /root`) what is your opinion about the files in my root directory?

Comment: The terminal output on your question looks as expected (I get the same on my system). What did you expect to see? What are you trying to achieve? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @navid Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your output is completely normal. Is there something in particular that you are looking for that you expected to find in `/root`? (other than roots desktop folder?)

Comment: @DavidFoerster @ElderGeek thanks to two of you. your comments was very helpful to me. just one more question. I want to make sure that my system works normal. I think I have lost some of my privileges on my system. (maybe I'm not. just let me see what is your opinion). try to copy a directory to desktop like this.
 `cp .config /home/yoursystemname/Desktop`
and then close the terminal and try to open this copied directory by double-clicking on it on your desktop.
can you open this directory? what happen when you try to do this?
thanks for your efforts to helping people and me.

Comment: @DavidFoerster and Elder Geek, if you are able to open this directory in the mentioned conditions (by double-clicking on it on your desktop) so why I'm not able to do it? if you are not able to do this and you face with a permission error is this just normal? shouldn't us have the permission to do this? as superusers or administrators or whatever like that?

Comment: In the terminal you are root, but not in the GUI. In the GUI you are still navid.That's the difference.

Comment: Also `ls` command shows that you have a file or folder named `Desktop` in `/root`. If you want to see all files, use `ls -a` to list hidden files too.

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Send me a notification here if you want to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think all this is a problem with terminology.

When experienced Linux-users talk about the root-directory, they mean the directory which is named `/`, yes, the name of this directory is just a single slash.
Look at the screenshot you provided in your last question ( [superuser issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910631/superuser-issues) ) and focus on the title bar, can you see the `/`? You are in the `/`-directory,

Unfortunatly the `/`-directory contains a directory which is named `root`. This is what leads to the confusion. This directory holds configuration-files for the user `root`, and only the user `root` has permissions to read, write or browse the content of this folder.

You are logged in as the user `navid`, not as user `root`, so you simply don't have permissions to even open this folder. The reason that the permissions are set up this way is to protect the operating system from unauthorized modifications, imagine what would happen if you delete an important system-file or modify it in a not proper way. It could affect system-stability or, in the worst case, render your operating system completely useless.

If you want to see or modify the contents of the `root`-directory ( correctly we should call it `/root`-directory, as `root` is a sub-directory of `/`), you need to learn how to gain root-privileges while you are logged in as user `navid`. And whenever you know how to gain root-privileges, this will be the moment when you have to start to be careful.

Please remind that we all are volunteers, working hard to get an income and spend a lot of our free time here to help out. We expect some effort from your side, kindness and patience are absolutely necessary.

If a question is `[on hold]`, it does not mean that the question is closed, you can still edit the question to improve it and the `[on hold]` might be retracted by a moderator after a review.

Comment: I added more information. please check it out if you would. thanks